# Request for help understanding a solution in a research paper

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization

I am having difficulty understanding a particular solution in a research paper I am reading.

Title: "Analysis of nonlinear duopoly game with
heterogeneous players"(2006)

Authors: Jixiang Zhang, Qingli Da, Yanhua Wang

I would appreciate your help in clarifying the steps involved.

Problem:
On page 142 of the paper, there is an inequality with the following condition:
\begin{equation}
\text{condition 2: } 1+\text{Tr}(\mathbf{J})+\text{Det}(\mathbf{J}) > 0
\end{equation}
The goal is to find the range of alpha values that violate this condition. And substitute the \begin{align*} Tr(J), \ Det(J), \ q_1^*, \ q_2^*.
\end{align*} previously proposed by the researcher.:

\begin{equation}
2 + \alpha a - \frac{ab(b + 2c_1)\alpha}{3b^2 + 4c_1c_2 + 4b(c_1 + c_2)} - \frac{4a(b + 2c_2)(b + c_1 + \frac{b^2}{8(b + c_2)})\alpha}{3b^2 + 4c_1c_2 + 4b(c_1 + c_2)}
\end{equation}

Then, differentiate with respect to alpha.
My result:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{a(b + 2c_2)(5b^2 + 4c_1c_2 + 4b(c_1 + c_2))}{2(b + c_2)(3b^2 + 4c_1c_2 + 4b(c_1 + c_2))}
\end{equation}

*** the range of alpha that the researcher considered is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\alpha < \frac{4(b + c_2)(3b^2 + 4c_1c_2 + 4b(c_1 + c_2))}{a(b + 2c_2)(5b^2 + 4c_1c_2 + 4b(c_1 + c_2))}
\end{equation}

I tried to solve this inequality using Mathematica, but the numerator and denominator of my solution were different from those in the paper. The constants also did not match. I am not sure where I made a mistake.

Questions:

Why does the inequality in the paper have different signs and constants compared to Mathematica's solution?
Is it okay to differentiate an inequality when it has a squared term and is difficult to solve otherwise? I noticed that other studies I have read did not use differentiation, but this paper did.

Comment: There are [different reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/1273570) why links to pictures aren’t great. It’s probably better to replicate the formulae from there using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) providing links only for reference.

Comment: @Aig Thank you for your previous advice. I've added the equations, as you requested. 
I would be grateful if you could review the equations and please let me know if there are any further changes required.

Comment: In view of [ultimate fate](https://plagiarism.repec.org/zhang-da-wang.html) of the paper you've cited, I'd suggest dropping your study of it and switching to a study of [the paper](https://plagiarism.repec.org/zhang-da-wang/zhang-da-wang2.pdf) of which it is apparently a very close copy.  Perhaps you'll have no difficulties with the latter.